# Draggable marker in map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3

I'm an example map shows the current location with the click of a button shows lat,long  , But I need a little change on the map 
Changes :

1 - marker on the map after click button be draggable to get new lat long and show address 
, in fact marker be fixed on the center map and map be draggable to get new address and new lat,long

My code is :

```js
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
   
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var map = null;
 function showlocation() {
  // One-shot position request.
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);
 }
 function callback(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lon = position.coords.longitude;
  document.getElementById('default_latitude').value = lat;
  document.getElementById('default_longitude').value = lon;
  var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: latLong
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
  map.setZoom(16);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
 function initMap() {
  var mapOptions = {
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
   zoom: 1,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    mapOptions);
 }
</script>
```

```html
<input type="button"  class="btn  pull-right map-btn" value="btn " onclick="javascript:showlocation()" />

<div id="map-canvas" style="height: 300px"></div>
  
<input type="text" id="default_latitude" placeholder="Latitude"/>
<input type="text" id="default_longitude" placeholder="Longitude"/>
```

Comment: What is the problem in above code?

Comment: marker not draggable ,  i want to marker on the map after click button be draggable to get new address and new lat long , in fact marker be fixed on the center map and map be draggable to get new address and new lat,long

Comment: Sorry codes were wrong , Be updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var map = null;
var marker;

  function showlocation() {
    // One-shot position request.
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);
  }
  function callback(position) {

if (marker != null) {
       marker.setMap(null);
    }

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById('default_latitude').value = lat;
    document.getElementById('default_longitude').value = lon;
    var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLong,
      draggable:true
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
    map.setZoom(16);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0]) {
        $('#default_latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
        $('#default_longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
     `enter code here` }
    }
  });
});

  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);



  function initMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
      zoom: 1,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: but after click on show location Btn other marker shows , and other problem is after change position of marker lat and long did not change , and in fact i want to marker be fix on center map and map be draggable

Comment: Still when I click on the button `showlocation` another marker added on the map, and marker not fix in map center and background map not draggble

Comment: What is the purpose of the button here? just to get the marker on current position?

Comment: set marker.setMap(null); in callback function.. I have updated the code above,,have a look

Comment: Thank you very much, now how can i fixed marker on center map and map be draggable to get new lat long

Comment: Map is already dragabble. and as we click on button marker is also coming in center then?

Comment: either we can make marker fixed or draggable..its not possible to make both for any marker. :)

Comment: in fact marker be fixed and map be draggable to get new lat and long